# Dropbox doesn't leave "Connecting..." state

Tags: dropbox

After installing Dropbox in 12.10 it doesn't connect properly. All files get synced without any problems, but in the drop down menu (icon in the top bar) it keeps showing "Connecting" for 3 days now... In 12.04 it shows account stats etc..

Any way to solve this?

Comment: This should probably be reported to the Dropbox people.

Comment: You can drop a bug-report for the dropbox devs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont know if there is any way to actually solve this right now, but I have the same problem. You could help about with clicking on the "this bug affects me too".
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1069113

For a little workaround you can check the status of your dropbox by using this from the terminal:

```
dropbox status
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Temporarily, I think you can solve with this:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/72/en

Comment: rebuilding settings did work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I tried this and it worked for me. I hope it will be the same with you:

Try this:

```
cd /media
sudo mkdir data
sudo chown <youruser> data
```

Where *youruser* is, obviously, different than *root*.

Now type this:

```
sudo blkid | grep UUID
```

You will be able to identify UUID and TYPE of your filesystem where dropbox folder is stored.

Copy the choosen pair somewhere. Now edit *fstab* `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

and append at the end of the file something like this:

```
UUID=yourUUID   /media/data yourTYPE    defaults    0   0
```

Ok. Now, last step:

```
dropbox stop
```

Check if is really stopped. If it isn't, kill it (You can use `ps` and `kill` commands).

Delete configuration:

```
rm -rf ~/.dropbox
```

and restart dropbox

```
dropbox start
```

It will be start syncing files from the internet.

Comment: This is more related to having a wrong fstab then Dropbox problems.